# Easiest way to count distinct number of rows in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I just did:

```
len(my_df.drop_duplicates())
```

Is there not a more elegant way to do this?
in R you can do:

```
nrow(distinct(my_df))
```

Which to me is very readable, drop_duplicates() feels worrying, because as new Python user, I get lost with what operations are happening in place and which ones you need to store/overwrite copies of for the environment to persist the change.

The fact that searching on google didn't give me a clear one click answer for what I'd think was a simple function worried me a bit...

Thanks!

Comment: add an example of what you are after. show some sample data with expected output

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas` you can do by another way `groupby` or `duplicated` with `sum`

```
df.groupby(list(df)).ngroup() 

(~df.duplicated()).sum()
```

Also as a `R` and `python` user, I know that is hard to switch from `R` to `pandas` , but the most common way is `drop_duplicates`

Comment: Sorry, df.groupby(list(df)).ngroup()  doesn't seem to give me what I want...I mean I can write a function that does this...but surely there's a function or method that simply takes a dataframe as an input, and outputs the number of distinct records? I just want a scalar 'n' output.

Comment: @Jamalan how about `df.duplicated` this method

Answer (score 0):

```
len(pd.unique(my_df))
```

you are looking for unique I guess.

Comment: my_df is 90 records and 3 variables, this gives me a broadcasting error for some reason